# not able to attach excel file from assets folder

Tags: android

I am not able to attach an excel file from assets folder using email intent in android. Can anyone please suggest what is wrong in the below code. The email opens but a message comes saying "unable to attach file".

```
            File xlsFile = new File("assets/test.xlsx");
    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(xlsFile);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent1.setType("application/excel");
        intent1.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Excel File for test");
        intent1.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"");
        intent1.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent1, "Send email..."));
```

Answer (score 2):

First, `assets/test.xlsx` is not a file on the Android device. It is an asset, packaged in your APK. Hence, `new File("assets/test.xlsx")`.

Second, even if there was a file at that path, third-party email apps cannot read it.

Either:

- Copy the file to external storage, then create a `Uri` to that and use it in your `Intent`, or
- Copy the file to internal storage and [use `FileProvider` to serve it](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html), or
- Use [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) to serve it straight from assets