# Sending Email with attachment from Asset folder

Tags: android, email, email-attachments

```
    //EMAIL SENDING CODE  FROM ASSET FOLDER
    email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
    subject = editTextSubject.getText().toString();
    message = editTextMessage.getText().toString();
    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("file/html");
    emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("content://com.example.deepa.xmlparsing/file:///android_assets/Combination-1.html"));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using"));
```

Finally, I'm getting the file from asset folder (Combination-1.html).

It is getting

> **Runtime error file not found exception.**

Is there any other way to send file attachment?

Comment: `openAssetFile(Uri uri, `. Please tell the value of uri.getPath(). And uri.getLastPathSegment().

Comment: `"file/html"`. You mean "text/html".

Comment: `My AssetFileDescriptor.java class file:`. No. Your custom content provider class. You could as well have mentioned in the subject trying to send a html file from assets using custom content provider. Please be more informative.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318573/not-able-to-attach-excel-file-from-assets-folder

Comment: @Ramesh Sambu - please read the post : [How to copy files from assets folder to sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/how-to-copy-files-from-assets-folder-to-sdcard) . Once you save an asset to external storage, continue with my post down below to send it as attachment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to send an email is to create an Intent of type ACTION_SEND :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{recipient_address});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Attachment test");
```

To attach a single file, add some extended data to Intent :

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File("/path/to/file")));
intent.setType("text/html");
```

Or use Html.fromHtml() to build html content:

```
intent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                 Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder()
                 .append("<h1>Heading 1</h1>")
                 .append("<p><a>http://www.google.com</a></p>")
                 .toString()));
```

For multiple attachments:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.setType("text/html");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test multiple");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "multiple attachments");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{recipient_address});
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File("/path/to/first/file")));
uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File("/path/to/second/file")));
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
```

Finish with a call to startActivity() passing intent.

Answer (score 3):

Create a File object of your asset folder file and attach this object to your email Intent.

And as mentioned in your Question ***runtime error file not found exception*** this may be cause the URL ***"file:///android_asset/"*** doesn't point to a particular directory, it is only used by WebView to address assets. Pulled that [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281245/get-folders-name-from-assets-directory/3281337#3281337)

you can open this as an input stream and covert this `InputStream` to `File`

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(activity.getAssets().open(myfile.pdf)));
```

Send this file object in email as follow.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND ,Uri.parse("mailto:")); 
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Card Set ");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(file));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Where `Intent.ACTION_SEND` used to send Email , `Intent.EXTRA_STREAM` for the attachments with email. you can have multiple `Intent.EXTRA_STREAM`in single intent to refer multiple attachments with `intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);`.

`intent.setType(String mimeType)` input param is represent the MIME type data that you want to get in return from firing intent(here intent instance).where setype can be

```
image/jpeg
audio/mpeg4-generic
text/html
audio/mpeg
audio/aac
audio/wav
audio/ogg
audio/midi
audio/x-ms-wma
video/mp4
video/x-msvideo
video/x-ms-wmv
image/png
image/jpeg
image/gif
.xml ->text/xml
.txt -> text/plain
.cfg -> text/plain
.csv -> text/plain
.conf -> text/plain
.rc -> text/plain
.htm -> text/html
.html -> text/html
.pdf -> application/pdf
.apk -> application/vnd.android.package-archive
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use following code to achieve your goal , and can change Hard coded string according your requirements .

```
String filename="contacts_sid.vcf"; 
File filelocation = new 
File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), filename);
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(filelocation); 
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
// Here you can set the type to 'email'
emailIntent .setType("abc.xyz.cursor.dir/email");
String to[] = {"android@gmail.com"};
emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
//  For the attachment
emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
// the mail subject
emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Find Attachments with email");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent , "Sending  email..."));
```

Answer (score -1):

**You can not share Asset folder file to other application without ContentProvider**. You can send file which can be accesible for every application.like some whare in intenal phone memory or sd card.

Sharing Asset [Check This Answer of @CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182250/how-to-share-images-inside-assets-folder-with-intent-to-other-application)

Or 
Read your text file and use @RonTLV Answer and mail.

Or
Copy File in intenal memory and add to sending launch.
Hope this answer will help.