# how to share images inside assets folder with intent to other application

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences, android-contentprovider

i want to share images inside an assets folder using intent to the following applications

- hangout
- whatsapp
- line chat
- viber
- tango
- wechat

i have try this code for whatsapp but it given me file not supported

```
public void  share (){


        String file = "file:///android_asset/food/apple.png";

        Uri filePath = Uri.fromFile(new File("content://com.example.zainabishaqmusa.postemoji/assets/gestures/aok.png"));

        final ComponentName name = new ComponentName("com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp.ContactPicker");
        Intent oShareIntent = new Intent();
        oShareIntent.setComponent(name);
        //oShareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        //oShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Website : www.google.com");
        oShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, filePath);
        oShareIntent.setType("image/png");
        oShareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        Gesture.this.startActivity(oShareIntent);

    }
```

Comment: You cannot reach a file in assets in that way. Please read the posts of today as some hours ago this question was asked too. Well kind off.

Comment: Mmmm you are also using a content scheme for a File object. Pretty confusing. Please remove the one or the other.

Comment: Why is there a sharedpreferences and android-contentprovider tag?

Answer (score 1):

You would need a `ContentProvider` that is capable of sharing content from assets. [My `StreamProvider` offers this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider), or you could write your own.